# How can I get Jenkins/Hudson to preserve file permissions?

Tags: file-permissions, hudson, jenkins

I have an file in my Hudson workspace which has permissions of 777. It's listed under "Files to archive", and appears under "Last Successful Artifacts" on the Project page. If I right-click-save it, it only has 644 permission. How can I preserve the set permissions?

I am running Hudson 1.386 standalone on Ubuntu 10.04, if that matters.

Comment: Would you mind if I changed that file? I have in mind `rm -rf /` for its new contents. In other words 777 is a bad idea.

Comment: Once you download it you can do whatever you want. And if you are the other person who has access to that job's workspace, sure, go ahead and change it there too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Hudson, and everything to do with your browser.  If you want to preserve file permissions, I'd recommend having Hudson tar the files up, which will maintain the permissions when you extract it on a *nix system.